# How can I inject javascript into webview with metamask api?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, uniswap

I want to connect the metamask wallet when I enter the UNISWAP in the "react-native-webview".
I know what you need for this is javascript injection, but I don't know where to start.
Can you give me a good example or direction?

[image]

Comment: did u solve it?? i m stuck in the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at these react web3 components.

1. [web3-react](https://github.com/Uniswap/web3-react)
2. [wallet connect](https://docs.walletconnect.com/quick-start/dapps/react-native)
3. [web3-ui](https://github.com/Developer-DAO/web3-ui)

Demo: https://web3-react-mu.vercel.app/

Comment: i tried .. none of them are actually injecting web3 into the webview i open with metamask.

Comment: can u give a detailed explanation ..